# Update class name in duplicate html tags

Tags: javascript

I have 2 div shown in below with same id,

```
<div id="dv1" class="oldClass">Div 1</div>

<div id="dv1" class="oldClass">Div 2</div>
```

I need add class attribute using java script and i had implemented shown in below,

```
var lstObj = document.getElementsByClassName(“oldClass”);
for (var i = 0; i < lstObj.length; i++) {
jQuery("#" + lstObj[i].id).addClass("highlight");
}
```

but every time assign in only 1st div shown in below,

```
<div id="dv1" class="oldClass highlight">Div 1</div>
<div id="dv1" class="oldClass">Div 2</div>
```

i need add “highlight” class in both div. Please help me.
Also please refer below link,

Please refer below link,

[https://forum.jquery.com/topic/update-class-name-in-duplicate-html-tags]

Regards,
Nirav

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same `id`.

Comment: I know that two elements with same id is wrong but my requirement is that so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from below forum site,

```
[https://forum.jquery.com/topic/update-class-name-in-duplicate-html-tags?reply=true]
```

Please follow below link to see solution,

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/sUBWd/8/]
```

Regards,
Nirav Parikh

Answer (score 0):

check on this `$('.oldClass').addClass('highlight')`

Comment: Please refer below link


https://forum.jquery.com/topic/update-class-name-in-duplicate-html-tags